# faster column-multiply in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multiplication

I have a pandas dataframe A that has 2 columns x and y. I want to multiply them like `B = A['x'] * A['y']`. Is there any faster way to do this? would `A['a'].mul(A['y'])` be faster?

Comment: In the docs, it says mul is equivalent to * so I doubt it will be faster. `Equivalent to dataframe * other, but with support to substitute a fill_value for missing data in one of the inputs. With reverse version, rmul.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check which is faster you can check the time that it takes for each case:
In Ipython or Jupiter would be:

```
%%timeit
    d['a'] * d['b']
```

For a dataframe like this one:

```
a = np.arange(0,10000)
b = np.ones(10000)

d = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([a,b]).T, columns=["a","b"])
```

Get your multiplication:

**1**- in pandas

```
d['a'] * d['b']
81.2 µs ± 977 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**2** - in numpy. avoiding pandas overhead

```
d['a'].values * d['b'].values
9.21 µs ± 41.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

... If you are worried so much about speed, use just numpy. Take advantage of the nice feature of pandas to allow you to access the array with the feature `values`.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is much faster, you use np.arrays if your columns are lengthy

```
import numpy as np

B=np.array(A.x)*np.array(A.y)
```

A quick test on my PC on a dataframe with 55K rows reduced the time from 0.78 sec (your original method) to 0.54 sec (above method)

Answer (score 0):

I could only agree with @IoaTzimas 's comment, Numpy is faster. So you'd be better off converting the Dataframe's columns that you want to multiply to Numpy `arrays` and work with them.

If you have the initial data in arrays, you can just convert them to a numpy array and use that.

If you have your data in a Dataframe and need to extract it beforehand you could do the following:

```py
from numpy import multiply as npMultiply

# get the values from the Dataframe to arrays
x_array = A['x'].values
y_array = A['y'].values

B = npMultiply(x_array, y_array)
```